# Evolution operator as a Laurent series of coupling constant

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time-evolution, non-perturbative, asymptotics

Let the Hamiltonian be $H_{0}+gV$, where $g$ is the coupling constant. In the interaction picture, the equation for the evolution operator is $i\frac{dU}{dt}=gV_{I}U$. What I am going to do is assume $U$ is a Laurent series of $g$. The motivation is that I hope that $U$ can capture the nonperturbative effect like $e^{-1/g}$ term.

So I assume $U=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\alpha_{n}(t)g^{n}$, for constant term I obtain $i\frac{d\alpha_{0}}{dt}=V_{I}\alpha_{-1}$. In this case, since if $g$ is zero, $U$ is just $e^{-iH_{0}t}$, so I let $\alpha_{0}=e^{-iH_{0}t}$ and plugged in in the equation, I obtain $e^{-iH_{0}t}H_{0}=V_{I}\alpha_{-1}$.

Let $H_{0}=\omega a^{\dagger}a$ and $V=e^{-iEt}a+e^{iEt}a^{\dagger}$, then $V_{I}=f(t)a-\overline{f(t)}a^{\dagger}$ for some function $f(t)$. The important point is, when I plugged this into equation $e^{-iH_{0}t}H_{0}=V_{I}\alpha_{-1}$, I cannot obtain meaningful results. Since LHS contains only product of $a^{\dagger}a$, while RHS must contain more than product of $a^{\dagger}a$ whatever $\alpha_{-1}$ is, so both side cannot match, Even $\alpha_{-1}=0$, it still cannot match.

So, what's wrong with my approach? If Dyson series is not analytic in $g$, why can't I assume it is a Laurent series?

Comment: Non-perturbative effects cannot be captured by a perturbative expansion. That's why they are called "non-perturbative".

Comment: PS - Try doing a Taylor expansion for the function $e^{-1/g^2}$ near $g=0$.

Comment: ＠Prahar I see you point. Still, the Laurent series of $e^{-1/g^{2}}$ is not zero and converge. If there is instanton effect in U, it should be captured by the Laurent series.

Comment: Why do you think so?!?! I have really not read this anywhere! The Laurent series does _not_ capture all the information that there is about a function so I really don't see why you are saying that instanton effects should be captured by Laurent series. Also the Laurent series of $e^{-1/g^2}$ about $g=0$ IS zero. Why do you say otherwise?

Comment: I agree that Laurent series of the above function is zero at g=0, but since we want to find behaviour of U when g is not zero, that is where the Laurent series works. If g not equal to zero, we can expand $e^{-1/g^2}=1-1/g^2+…$ by Laurent expansion, so there should be a nonzero contribution from $1/g^2$ terms. But I agreed that Laurent series cannot captures all nonperturbative effects.

Comment: $e^{-1/g^2} = 1 - 1/g^2 + \cdots$ is the TAYLOR expansion of the function around $g=\infty$, NOT around $g=0$. Perturbative calculations will NOT capture the expansion around $g=0$ because $e^{-1/g^2}$ because it is not analytic there. You can check that $\partial_{\bar z} e^{-1/z^2} \neq 0$ at $z=0$.

Comment: I pulled this from the Wikipedia article on Laurent series regarding this function - "By replacing x with $-1/x^2$ in the power series for the exponential function, we obtain its Laurent series which converges and is equal to $e^{-1/x^2}$ for all complex numbers $x$ **except at the singularity $x=0$.**"

Comment: This is exactly my point. The series converges EXCEPT $g=0$, which is the range we care. Remember that we want the evolution operator $U$ when $g$ IS NOT ZERO. For $g=0$, we already know the solution, we don't care about the expansion at that point diverges or not.

Comment: But in perturbation theory you are trying to evaluate the structure of the theory at generic (but small) $g$ by doing calculations _at_ $g=0$. This is the essence of perturbation theory. We cannot do this for non-perturbative effects because their Laurent expansion is precisely ill-defined _at_ $g=0$.